# MongoDB add a 'self' type

Tags: mongodb

I am new at MongoDB. I am trying to create 2 db's :
1 - Dogs
2 - Person

I want a person to have 0, 1 or more dogs, and a partner (who is also a person)

tried to do:

```
var dogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    breed: String
});

var Dog = mongoose.model("Dog", dogSchema);

var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    partner: this,
    dogs: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Dog"
        }
        ]
});

var Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);
```

But when I try to create a new person, things getting complicated.

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: `partner: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: "Person" }` - does it works?

Comment: I tried it before i tried "this". didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This code work fine for me:

```
"use strict"

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  parent: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Category"},
  subcategory: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Category"},
});

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);

async function run() {
  await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mongoose-test");
  const category = new Category({name:"Name"});
  const subcategory = new Category({name:"Name 2", parent:category});
  category.subcategory = subcategory;
  await Promise.all([category.save(), subcategory.save()]);
};
run();
```

Mongo:

```
> db.categories.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59f4a8f32ebdb940cc2bed3a"), "subcategory" : 
ObjectId("59f4a8f32ebdb940cc2bed3b"), "name" : "Name", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59f4a8f32ebdb940cc2bed3b"), "name" : "Name 2", 
"parent" : ObjectId("59f4a8f32ebdb940cc2bed3a"), "__v" : 0 }
```